# Array + why arrays are not in the Right place

Tags: linux, bash, array

I set an array named “disks” to the following words - sdb sdc sdd

in bash shell:

```
declare -A disks
Machine=worker01
disks[$Machine]="sdb sdc sdd"
```

now we print all words as the following:

```
echo ${disks[@]}
sdb sdc sdd
```

now we want to print the first item ( that should be sdb )

```
echo ${disks[0]}
```

but no output

the same with:

```
echo ${disks[1]}

echo ${disks[2]}
```

also with:

```
echo ${disks[3]}

echo ${disks[4]}
```

…

what is wrong here?

also not as:

```
for i in {1..100}
> do
> echo ${disks[$i]}
> done
```

so how can I print the first words of the array “disks” - when `Machine=worker01`

```
echo ${disks[$Machine]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning to `disks[worker01]`, but trying to read from `disks[0]` etc. The indexes are different.

As someone commented, Bash doesn't have multidimensional arrays, and that's what you really would need here. You can simulate that roughly with with space-separated strings, but then you need to split the string explicitly.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A disks
disks["host1"]="sda sdb"
disks["host2"]="sda sdb sdc"

for m in "${!disks[@]}"; do
    # split the string to array 'd'
    IFS=' ' read -a d <<< "${disks[$m]}"
    printf "$m has disk %s\n" "${d[@]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you declare `Machines` when you never use it after?

```
$ disks=(sdb sdc sdd)
$ echo ${disks[0]}
sdb
$ echo ${disks[1]}
sdc
$ echo ${disks[2]}
sdd
```

Comment: because each machine have the uniq disks

Comment: for example how to print only the first word from -  echo ${disks[$Machines]}

Comment: bash doesn't support multi-dimensional arrrays at all.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in `${disks[worker01]}`, not in `${disks[0]}`.

I am also wondering if you are trying to use an array of arrays: An array of machines, each with an array of disks.

Comment: because we have 20 machines as worker01 , worker02 , etc , and each machine have the uniq disks , so my target is to build array of machines and each machines hold the disks

Comment: I am confused. Linguistically that makes no sense: If you were to walk into my cheese shop with a ”I love cheese” t-shirt, and I was to ask you ”Would you like some cheese”, and you were to reply “Because I like dairy products”, then I would be confused, and no more informed about your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking just to print an specific value you could use:

```
echo ${disks[$Machine]} | awk '{print $1}'
```

where $1 = index 0

OUTPUT:

```
sdb
```